# Detect hardware button press while android device is locked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to detect hardware button press, specially power button long press while the device is locked. I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` that starts when the device is locked & unlocked. but I'm stuck after that...
any solution?

My code sample:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receivers.UnlockReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Receiver class:

```
public class UnlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private String TAG = "UnlockReceiver";


        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Now I'm trying to detect power button 
            // press & long press while the device is locked
        }

    }
```

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
 super.onPause();

PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)  
      {
        if (powerManager != null)
          {
            isScreenOn = powerManager.isInteractive();
           }
    } 
  else
       {
        if (powerManager != null) 
        {
            isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
        }
    }

    if (!isScreenOn) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
        }

        // The screen has been locked

    }
}
```

Comment: it only detects is the app is now in foreground or background :/

Comment: it detects in foreground

Comment: How can I use it to detect hardware key press while it is in foreground inside the lockscreen?

Comment: Am using  this code in activity for Lock Screen Application.